# Need a regex to match state abbreviations in the middle of a URL path

Tags: regex

I have a URL in two forms:

1. `/new-doctors/name-of-region`
   | ex: `/new-doctors/northern-california`
2. `/new-doctors/<state abbreviation>/name-of-city`
   | ex. `/new-doctors/ca/san-francisco`

The first part of the path is always the same (`new-doctors`)

The regex should produce only the second item, that is, only this URLs with a two letter state abbreviation.

The logic I am looking for is:

- path starts with "/new-doctors/"
- then has any two letters a-z
- then has another "/"

This will match because URL type 1 will always be more than 2 letters in the second piece of the URL

Comment: Try [`\/new-doctors\/([a-z]{2})\/`](https://regex101.com/r/gC0vF7/1) or [`\/new-doctors\/(.*?)\/`](https://regex101.com/r/gC0vF7/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like so: `\/new-doctors\/[a-z]{2}\/` (example available [here](https://regex101.com/r/tM9xQ9/1)).

The expression will match `/new-doctors/` which is followed by 2 (`{2}`) lower case letters (`[a-z]`) which is followed by another /.

Comment: thank you! why the heck is my question being downvoted?

Comment: @duggi: When posting here make sure to include what have you tried.

Answer (score 1):

To match the second url you can use the following regex:

```
\/new-doctors\/[a-zA-Z]{2}\/[^/]+
```

If you want to match both using same regex, you can use

```
\/new-doctors(?:\/[a-zA-Z]{2})?\/[^\/]+
```

Using `(?:\/[a-zA-Z]{2})?` I am making the abbreviation portion as optional inside url.

Comment: thank you. accepted answer above b/c it was a little more succint to my question, but your effort is appreciated.